# Compare string between listboxes

Tags: c#, listbox, compare

I have two listboxes with several data, ListBox1 have this format:

```
C:\Users\Charlie\Desktop\Trials\Trial0004COP.txt
```

and in my ListBox2:

```
Trial0004COP
```

How can I check if Trial0004COP exists in my listbox1? I used Contain() but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
bool found = listBox1.Items.Cast<string>()
                           .Where(x => x.Contains("Trial0004COP"))
                           .Any();
```

Or to make it more accurate use [`String.EndsWith()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2333wewz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method but you also have to add `".txt"` if you want to make it works:

```
bool found = listBox1.Items.Cast<string>()
                           .Where(x => x.EndsWith("Trial0004COP.txt"))
                           .Any();
```

**Edit :**

> Hi Fuex, I'm using OpenFileDialog to select a file, then this file is
>   added to my listbox1 with all the Directory name. In my listbox2 I
>   read another file that contains several Trials000""" and add them to
>   it, I want to know if the file that I selected from the open dialog
>   exist in my listboz2

Yes can do it in this way:

```
bool found = false;
if(openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK){
   found = listBox.Items.Cast<string>()
                        .Where(x => x.EndsWith(openFileDialog.FileName))
                        .Any();

   if(!found)
      MessageBox.Show(openFileDialog.FileName + " doesn't exist in listBox1"); //show a message
}
```

Comment: Hi Fuex, I'm using OpenFileDialog to select a file, then this file is added to my listbox1 with all the Directory name.
In my listbox2 I read another file that contains several Trials000""" and add them to it, I want to know if the file that I selected from the open dialog exist in my listbox2.
Well only the Trial000"""" part.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend something like:

```
var searchString = "Trial0004COP";
var isFound = false;
foreach(var name in listbox1.items)
{
    if (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(name).ToLower() == searchString.ToLower())
    {
        _IsFound = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that in Windows, file names are case-preserving but not case-sensitive, so you need to check the file name ignoring its case.

You could do it in a single line in *Linq*, if that's your thing.

```
var searchString = "Trial0004COP";
var isFound = listBox1.Items.Cast<string>()
                            .Any(x => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x).ToLower() == searchString.ToLower());
```

Comment: Hi Scott, actually Trial0004COP is one of many files that exist in my listbox2, I want to know if the files in my listbox1 matches with the files in my listbox2, as you can see they have different names, but they have in common the Trial000""" part.

Comment: Then you could do the same thing with an outer foreach on the other listbox. You could probably do that in a single Linq statement too, just for fun.

Answer (score 0):

Using *LINQ* you can do:

```
listBox1.Items.Select(e => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(e as string)).Contains("Trial0004COP");
```